# Как сверстать данные кнопки?

Tags: html, jquery, css

radiobutton или просто div'ами?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Radiobutton конечно, и потом менять стили его

Comment: Не уверен, конечно, но возможно, что Radiobutton нужно поместить в div

Comment: так просмотрите код на странице с которой взяли скрин)

Comment: @yolosora не нужно умничать. очевидно, я бы сюда не писал, если бы это был сайт.
Это скриншот psd макета

Answer (score 2):

```css
.button-radio{
    padding: 15px 25px;
}

.radio {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity: 0;
    margin: 10px 0 0 7px;
}
.radio + label {
    position: relative;
    width: 300px;
    padding: 0 0 0 55px;
    /* margin: 15px 25px; */
    cursor: pointer;
    display: inline-block;
    line-height: 3;
    border-radius: 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
.radio + label:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 14px;
    left: 15px;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    border: 1px solid #CDD1DA;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #FFF;
}
.radio + label:after {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 18px;
    left: 19px;
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #9FD468;
    box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    opacity: 0;
    transition: .2s;
}

.radio:checked + label{
    background: #0f74a8;
    color: #fff;
}

.radio:checked + label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
.radio:focus + label:before {
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3px rgba(255,255,0,.7);
}
```

```html
<div class="button-radio">
    <input type="radio" class="radio" id="radio" />
    <label for="radio">А я переключаю радиокнопку</label>
</div>
```

Дальше переделать под себя=)